# C# Custom Config Section

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationsection

I have a custom config section:

```
  <myServices>
      <client clientAbbrev="ABC">
        <addressService url="www.somewhere.com" username="abc" password="abc"/>
      </client>
      <client clientAbbrev="XYZ">
        <addressService url="www.somewhereelse.com" username="xyz" password="xyz"/>
      </client>
  <myServices>
```

I want to refer to the config as:

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myServices") as ServicesConfigurationSection;
var abc = section.Clients["ABC"];
```

but get a

> cannot apply indexing to an expression
>   of type 'ClientElementCollection'

How can I make this work?

client element collection:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(ClientElement), AddItemName = "client")]
public class ClientElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new ClientElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((ClientElement) element).ClientAbbrev;
    }
}
```

Client element:

```
public class ClientElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("clientAbbrev", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ClientAbbrev
    {
        get { return (string) this["clientAbbrev"]; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("addressService")]
    public AddressServiceElement AddressService
    {
        get { return (AddressServiceElement) this["addressService"]; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to `ClientElementCollection`

Something like

```
public ClientElement this[string key]
{
     get
     {
           return this.Cast<ClientElement>()
               .Single(ce=>ce.ClientAbbrev == key);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did find that if I set the "IsKey" attribute of the ConfigurationProperty for the ClientAbbrev property in ClientElement my indexer could be:

Comment: public new ClientElement this[string clientAbbreviation]
        {
            get { return (ClientElement) BaseGet(clientAbbreviation); }
        }